# How do I comment in Power Query M?

Tags: comments, powerquery, m

Is there a way to comment M code / comment out lines or blocks of code?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

M supports two different types of comments:

- Single line comments can be started with //
- You can comment out multiple lines or comment out text in the middle of a line using /* */ (e.g. `= 1 + /* some comment */ 2`)

Comments might seem to disappear in the formula bar if they are at the end of the line, but they are still there. You can verify this by looking at your code in the Advanced Editor.